# Memory error (недостаток памяти, я так понимаю)

Tags: python-2.x, matlab, numpy, outofmemoryerror

Возникла странная проблема. Есть необходимость из несольких массивов собрать один, однако Питон не согласен и пишет ошибку `MemoryError`в моем скрипте это выглядит так

`F = np.array([C3,C1,-Q1,A1,-F1])` , где `C3,C1,Q1,A1,F1`это тоже маccивы.

В принципе, в `MatLab` все работало, а тут не хочет. 
Есть идея о том, что может можно наложить массивы друг на друга не в общем файле, а по частям, но как это можно реализовать, если в конечном итоге мне нужна целая траектория, шаги которой как раз записаны в этих массивах. 
Может у кого есть идеи, как избежать этой ошибки?

Comment: Приведите размерности массивов (т.е. вывод `print(C3.shape, C1.shape, ...)`) и укажите какие типы данных используются

Comment: ((5, 3), (10, 3), (6, 3), (10, 3), (10, 3)). Тип данных по умолчанию использую float. Может ошибка в реализации!? ибо я в виде функции F хотела сделать объединение всех этих массивов. Не знаете ли, может это можно реализовать как то по-другому?

Comment: Вы хотите получить в результате матрицу размерности (41, 3) ?

Comment: Да, получается, что в одном цикле я хочу получить такую матрицу.

Answer (score 3):

*okey. Не знаю, понадобится ли это кому-то, но так поняла, что тут принято писать ответ на вопрос, если ты его нашел сам.*

Проблема была в использование `np.array`, за счет этого писались матрицы в матрицы и происходило нагромождение. Гораздо уместнее было использовать `F = np.vstack((C3,C1,-1*Q1,A1,-1*F1))`, что в свою очередь позволило бы записать массивы друг за другом и реализовать задуманное.

*Всем спасибо, кто пытался помочь решить данную проблему.*